# How to create center raised tabbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I want to create the TabBar as like Below image:

[image]

Here, all tab bar are normal. Just they are custom made. Now i want to create the Tab Bar as like above image. In which the center Tab is raised.

So what should i have do to make it possible ?

If is there any demo then it will be good.

Please help me.

Comment: Redesign your app for Android, straight iPhone ports are weak.

Comment: you can find demo [from this link](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/custom-tabbar-android/)

Comment: @Girish Bhutiya. Thanks for answer but i have already solved it.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer i need to do same tabbar could you please tell me how could i do that.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer Can you please help me how can i display image in center of tabbar tabs i am facing difficulty to do this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can set the Background image in Tab widget as

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_h);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.live);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.camera);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.Messege);
```

create the image as other four like Their Top 20% as Transparent and middle camera create as your Curve base . you will achieve your goal as this.

Like this where grey part is Transparency part.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes I have seen you image but its in Square image. I want the center tab as i have in my Question post.

Comment: No need to change Centre image as i show only need to change other Four Image like HOME imaeg. it will be set,

Comment: hardik Gajjar: Thanks. Let me try it. You mean i have to put other images as 20% less in height compare to Center image right ??

Comment: all the images height will same except four images 20% Top ratio Make Transparent as shown in above image.

Comment: ok I got you. So if i want to use selector for it then i also have to make the same image for press event right ?

Comment: I have use this code. Its look fine. but i am not able to get the Intent.

Comment: @HardikGajjar i have done like this but getting Nullpointer exception.can you help me out

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn1" />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/btn1"        
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"      
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn3"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

         <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>     

         <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>     

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>                                         

</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I'm get rid off build in TabWidget and setting up my own by LinearLayout.
Later you just need to set onClick function in main Tab Activity.

Like:

```
public void onClick(View v)
    {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                    case R.id.btn1: 
                            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
                            break;
                    case R.id.btn2:
                            tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                            break;
                    case R.id.btn3:
                            tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
                            break;
                    case R.id.btn4:
                            tabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
                            break;
                    case R.id.btn5:
                            tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
                            break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what about center tab. I want to raised it in round shape.

Comment: you are doing it by using RelativeLayout as the main holder.

Comment: will you please give full instruction of how to make it ?

Comment: what you don't know? Where do you have an issue?