# Customized Tab-Bars in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, tabs, uinavigationbar

How to create customized tab-bars in android not using images ? I need to create a tab-bar similar like this...

[image]

Comment: you can find demo [from this link](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/custom-tabbar-android/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found the answer for my question in stackoverflow itself

refer the answer done by Hardik Gajjar in the following question:

[How to create center raised tabbar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764046/how-to-create-center-raised-tabbar-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can associate a view to your tab:

```
tabHost.newTabSpec("name").setIndicator(R.id.your_view)
```

Comment: Given the question, I believe this answer is lacking a lot of fidelity. Maybe an example of the layout that the indicator resides inside of. Could also use a little bit of a preface and links to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom view for each tab button, and for the camera tab return a different view. I think something like this:

```
private void fillTabHost() {

    setupTab(ONE, new Intent().setClass(this, Activity.class), "title",R.drawable.icon);
    setupTab(TWO, new Intent().setClass(this, Activity.class), "title", R.drawable.icon);
    setupTab(THREE, new Intent().setClass(this, Activity.class), "title",R.drawable.icon);
    setupTab(FOUR, new Intent().setClass(this, Activity.class), "title",R.drawable.icon);
    setupTab(FIVE, new Intent().setClass(this, Activity.class), "title",R.drawable.icon);
}

private void setupTab(final String tag, Intent intent, int label, int icon) {
    View tabview = createTabView(tag, mContext, label, icon);
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}

private static View createTabView(String tag, final Context context, final int text, final int icon) {
    if(tag.equals("THREE")){
        // TODO return your CAMERA view
    }else{
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsIcon);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(icon);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        tv.setText(text);
    }
    return view;
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: i didn't understand how to shape the selected item round like that..means bulging that portion outside..if you have any idea in customizing such a way..please help me..thanks